# How to make an audio play/pause button?

Tags: html, audio, mp3, media

I recently learned about embedding audio in html like below.

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="sample.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Which displays something like a rectangle with various options on it like pause/play, download, set volume etc.

But how can I instead of this "audio playing rectangle" have a button that when clicked plays the audio once and on clicking on it while the audio is playing pauses it and on clicking again continuous playing.

Comment: At least upvote useful Answers if you don't like to accept them... Only takes per click to show "Thanks" to each one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript to perform such actions.

Try the following

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    myAudio.pause()
  } else {
    myAudio.play();
  }
};
myAudio.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};
```

Just replace the parameters to yours.

Comment: do i add the mp3 link to an href of a link button or what? would be grateful for a js fiddle!

Comment: @AsifAli this is javascript code wich you will need to include it before </body> tag with <script> above code </script>. also you need to set myAudio id for your audio tag as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example with pure JS. I am using a class on button to know if audio is playing or not, you can use the same class for different UI when button in play/pause state.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/p4mksfm1/

```
<audio id="testAudio" hidden src="https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<button id="playAudio">Play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
  if(this.className == 'is-playing'){
    this.className = "";
    this.innerHTML = "Play"
    audio.pause();
  }else{
    this.className = "is-playing";
    this.innerHTML = "Pause";
    audio.play();
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: you forgot to close the tag </script> but it works fine here ;)

Comment: Thanks, fixed the </script>

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use <video> HTML tag, then the same JS should work. Here is a simple example of video tag: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp